# How to put the title center of pdf by using grails export plugin?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-controller

I have exported pdf by using export-plugin in grails. Now my problem is to put the title  in the center of pdf. What code i need to write in the controller to align this title center?

Answer (score 1):

```
def export={
def data = userService.list(params)
if(params?.format && params.format != "html")
{
response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${params.controller}.${params.extension}")
List fields = ["username","email","clientName","role","status","timeZone"]
Map labels = ["username": "User Name","email":"Email ID","clientName":"Client Name","role":"Role","status":"Status","timeZone":"Time Zone"]
// Formatter closure
def upperCase = { domain, value -> return value.toUpperCase() }
Map formatters = [name: upperCase]
Map parameters = ["column.widths": [0.3, 0.4,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3]]
exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream, data.exportData, fields, labels,   formatters,parameters)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You customizing the icon by not using grails export tag but u can simply creat your own export controller and then u can call the grails export's export service to achive your goal with the following parameter

Comment: <li>
<a href="${request.getContextPath()}/user/export/?format=excel&extension=xls&search=${search}">
<img src="../images/skin/excel.png" title="Excel" style="padding-bottom: 3px;" >
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Excel
</a>
</li>